# Sending images from client to server with sockets

Tags: java, image, sockets

I want to send images from a client to a server in java. I found one way to do this is with sockets. My code is as follows:

Server side: thread waiting for client sockets and receiving the image when a client connects:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {   
        try(Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter outText = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader intText = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {

            try {
                // Get image info
                String imageInfo = inText.readLine();
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                // Handle input
                String[] split = imageInfo.split(";");
                String typeStr = split[0];
                String name = split[1];
                ServerImageType type = ServerImageType.fromInt(Integer.valueOf(typeStr));

                // Save image
                SaveImageThread saveImageThread = new SaveImageThread(image, name, type);
                saveImageThread.start();

                // Respond
                outText.println(name + " OK");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.out("The server is in pain: " + e);
            } 
        }
    }

    try {
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Client side:

```
public void sendImage(BufferedImage image, String name, ServerImageType imageType) throws IOException {
    try(Socket clientSocket = new Socket(serverName, txPort);
           PrintWriter outText = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
           BufferedReader inText = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()))
    ) {
        // Send image info
        String imageInfo = imageType.getId() + ";" + name;
        outText.println(imageInfo);

        // Send image
        ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        // Receive acknowledgement
        String input = inText.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server answered: " + input);
    }
}
```

Problem: the server gets stuck on the *ImageIO.read(...* line.. Any ideas?

Comment: Describe your protocol. Looks like there's text before the actual image data (bytes)? You're opening two streams btw (reader/inputstream)

Comment: Yes, the idea is that the client first sends a string to the server, with the image type (int) and a name. Next the image is send. Finally the client waits for an acknowledgement from the server.
The server receives the type and the name as a string, next receives the image, and answers with an acknowledge

Comment: I would open just one inputstream to parse all that. Also, have you checked the contents of that inputstream you're passing to ImageIO?

Comment: The streaming with ImageIO works, only after I added the extra data strings (type, name and acknowledgement) problems occurred

Comment: I meant: have you checked the contents of the inputstream passed to ImageIO *after* you added the text?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a clientSocket.getOutputStream().flush().